# Категория залога

Tags: морфология

1. Может ли при глаголе возвратно-среднего залога иметься второстепенный член предложения в форме Т.п., но без значения субъекта? Предположим, что нижеприведенная конструкция страдательная, но как-то странно будет звучать преобразование "взоры меняют их". Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в этом вопросе.

***Они меняются взорами.***

2. **И ещё вопрос:** может ли при страдательном залоге отсутствовать субъект действия, но подразумеваться? К примеру:

***Груз доставляется***.

Comment: Google Вам в помощь: "груз доставляется" https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22груз+доставляется%22&newwindow=1&client=safari&hl=ru-ru&prmd=vin&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT8ZPTq4LtAhVpo4sKHZxsDKcQ_AUoBnoECBwQBg&biw=768&bih=960

Comment: А что это такое "возвратно-средний залог", собственно говоря, если присмотреться к примерам повнимательнее? Абсолютно бесполезная категория (т.е все, что ни актив, ни пассив).  "Они меняются взорами." - это реципрок. "субъект действия" - это, как правило, агенс.

Answer (score 1):

> Может ли при глаголе возвратно-среднего залога иметься второстепенный
> член предложения в форме Т.п., но без значения субъекта?

Ну да, а что? Напротив, я как-то не соображу, а в каких случаях творительный падеж имеет значение субъекта? Фо фразах типа "Выпускники факультета работают переводчиками" творительный -  не субъект, а всего лишь признак субъекта. В остальных случаях творительный или инструмент (груз доставляется курьером), или объект ("Они меняются марками").

> Они меняются взорами.

А что это значит? Марки в качестве объекта обмена вас бы устроили? ну вот, они меняются марками. Марки тут не субъект, поэтому ваша попытка представить дело так, что "марки *их* меняют" несостоятельна изначально

> груз доставляется

Фраза в таком виде выглядит незаконченной, но если добавить, скажем, "в срок до трех суток", то никаких претензий вообще нет.

Может меня и поправят, но как я понимаю, представление о существовании этого возвратно-среднего залога - идея достаточно новая, как и вообще теория о категории залога у собственно глагола  (не у причастия). С этим еще предстоит разбираться, Возможно, мы по-разному представляем суть этой теории

Для меня, например, не ясно, а есть ли у глаголов в ваших примерах ("они обмениваются" и "груз доставляется") категория залога? Ведь по этой теории часть глаголов и из значений вообще находится вне  системы залога. Может, в этом все дело, не?

(+) ====

Немножко погорячился. Некоторые авторы действительно полагают, что что во фразах типа "***шхуну затерло льдом"*** или ***"потерявшегося мальчика искали всем поселком"*** лед и даже посёлок выступают субъектом. Спорно, но даже если и так, то это ничего не добавляет к сказанному.

Comment: О залоге и актантной деривации хорошо написано в книге Плунгяна "Введение в грамматическую семантику" (2011), глава 5, сс. 251-307